# Can someone check this regex statement please?

Tags: java, regex, spring, apache-camel, lookbehind

I just need to verify that this regex statement will do what I want.

Given the following json string

```
{"a":"1","Provider":"WebHook","b":"2"}
```

I need to ensure that the following regex

```
(?<=\bProvider":")\w+
```

Will always return the word following the string **Provider":"**

In this case, the word following string **Provider":"** is **WebHook**, but it could be any word.  I have control over this word, so it will never contain non-ascii characters.

I will be using this expression in Apache Camel, which uses the java regex engine.

Can anyone spot any pitfalls in my strategy.

Comment: Why not parse the JSON string?

Comment: The pitfall in your strategy is that you propose to use a regular expression for what is fundamentally a proper parsing task which is already supported by many libraries.

Comment: ... now you have two problems...

Comment: `{"Provider":"Hello\"World\""}`, `{"Not-The-\"Provider":""}`, `{"a":'still not a "Provider":"just a string"'}` - should I keep going? The alternative is `JSON data = parseJSON(str); JSON provider = data['Provider'];` (on an imagined parser, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks for the advice guys.  I bit the bullet and did things the right way, instead of parsing the regex.  Here's my solution:

I built a service which uses the org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.  This class takes the exchange body as an argument. It looks like this.

```
public class ProviderTypeWrangler {

    public String getProvider(String json) {

        try {

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Integration integration;
            integration = mapper.readValue(json, Integration.class);
            return integration.getProvider();
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            return "";
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "";
        }

    }

}
```

I then used the [routing slip](http://camel.apache.org/routing-slip.html) pattern to provide access to this service.  If anyone thinks another EIP would be appropriate, I'd be open for suggestions.  Anyway, here's an example of that.

```
public class WufooIntegrationRoutingSlip {

    @RoutingSlip
    public String slip(String body) {
        String answer = "activemq:noProducerDefined";
        ProviderTypeWrangler wrangler = new ProviderTypeWrangler();
        String producer = wrangler.getProvider(body);
        Logger mylogger = Logger.getLogger("log4j.logger.org.apache.camel");
        if (!producer.equals("")) {
            mylogger.info("Body:"+body);
            answer = "activemq:"+producer;
        }
        return answer;
    }

}
```

Then, in my camel.xml file I exposed this routing slip as a bean

```
<bean id="integrationBean" class="com.wufoo.camel.WufooIntegrationRoutingSlip"/>
```

And I used that bean to route the exchange to the correct queue.

```
<route errorHandlerRef="dlc" autoStartup="true" id="IntegrationQueue" xmlns:ns2="http://camel.apache.org/schema/web" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <description>Send all integrations here.  Logic will parse to individual queue based on Provider.</description>
    <from uri="activemq:integration"/> 
    <bean ref="integrationBean"/>
</route>
```

I learned a lot about camel and spring along the way, so thanks to the commenters for pushing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

While parsing is the right solution here, a regex meeting the criteria is not hard to construct:

```
/"Provider":"(.*?)"/
```

using perl style regexs